# Third Sub Class slot

Tags: destiny

I found [this reddit thread](http://www.reddit.com/r/DestinyTheGame/comments/2csh7r/there_will_not_be_a_third_subclass_people/) recently after wondering what was happening with the third empty sub-class slot in the Character menu.

The gist of it is that there are three "Elements" - Solar, Void, and Arc. Each class has a combination of 2/3:

- **Titan:** Arc/Void
- **Hunter:** Solar/Arc
- **Warlock:** Void/Solar

The idea behind this is so that you will be inclined to use *at least* two of the three classes, to gain access to all the elements. However, there is also a third, empty sub-class slot; leading me to believe something's coming...

The link I provided above suggests this will be a mix 'n' match style subclass, where you can select abilities from either sub-class to create your own custom one.

**Does anyone know what this third slot is actually for?**

[image: Third Empty Subclass slot]

Comment: *"The link I provided above"*, what link?

Comment: @Memor-X Whoops, sorry! Edited and added the link

Comment: This is speculating at developer intent as this feature has yet to be implemented currently.

Comment: @MichaelFrank It is fairly close. The slot is there but it's unclear what it's for.

Comment: I am fairly certain that Bungie would have posted some information about this if they really wanted us to know, and everything else is just speculating. This answer cannot be answered until Bungie comes forward with information, or they release a patch that introduces that subclass (or removes the slot).

Comment: Bungie like to "have fun" with the audience. Their sign off "Love Bungie" and their new error messages are just a couple of examples. It would fit that they're keeping secrets, with just a few clues scattered here and there. They hardly seem like a company that leaves things unfinished.

Comment: The [rumor](http://au.ibtimes.com/articles/570229/20141021/destiny-third-subclass-weapon-super-grenade-upgrade.htm) is that bungie is releasing a third subclass with december's expansion pack.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**EDIT:** With the announcement of the Taken King DLC, a new subclass for each class has been revealed, coming this September:

- Titan: Sunbreaker (solar)
- Warlock: Stormcaller (arc)
- Hunter: Nightstalker (void)

**Note:** The following information was true upon original release of the game (pre June 2015), but new subclasses have since been announced.

This slot is due to the way subclasses were supposed to work.  The mechanic I'll describe below was removed on the day one [patch](http://www.bungie.net/7_update-101---patch-notes/en/news/news?aid=12125):

> Removed subclass locking from builds.

Basically, the way subclasses were supposed to work was as follows:

1. You level up a subclass all the way, choosing which perks you wanted.
2. The final ability "locked" the subclass (can't change perks anymore) and gave you a slight boost to stats
3. Now that you've locked this subclass, you can start leveling a new subclass (either the same or your other option) with an exp bonus to level it faster

If that wasn't clear enough, see this [article](http://destinynews.net/subclass-locking-faq/)

The point of this was to experiment with different builds.  They removed this feature in favor of freely swapping between subclasses.  It seems it was an oversight to leave the third subclass slot in the character menu.

Comment: Although this is correct, the Grimiore now has slots and points for the third class, which when locking existed in the beta, it didn't have those. Bungie *may* be planning to release third subclass in the future, but we dont know for sure

Answer (score 1):

With the release of the new [Taken King DLC](http://www.gamezone.com/news/destiny-the-taken-king-new-subclasses-detailed-sunbreaker-stormcaller-and-nightstsalker-3417732) 3 new subclasses have (finally) been announced for each Class -

- Titan: [Sunbreaker](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Sunbreaker)
- Warlock: [Stormcaller](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Stormcaller)
- Hunter: [Nightstalker](http://destiny.wikia.com/wiki/Nightstalker)

This allows for each Class to have access to all 3 subclass types (Void, Sol, and Arc). Each of these subclasses opens up new abilities and weapons for each class.