# How to use Warlock's blink effectively?

Tags: destiny

I've tried using it, and from what I see basically it lets you teleport for a distance and direction, both depending on your momentum. I find this highly limiting when I want to use it to dodge projectiles, which is what I'm assuming that it's meant for. Therefore, there doesn't seem to be much reason to pick blink over the other glide abilities.

Comment: The Hunter also has this ability (and presumably the Titan will when the third class unlocks).

Comment: @Eben Any new info on the [third sub class slot?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/184955/third-sub-class-slot)

Comment: Nothing beyond speculation that I've been able to find so far.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Blink ability is meant for exactly that: dodging.

Most people have some difficulty with it initially because they're so used to the Glide jump. [IGN released a video](http://youtu.be/hkKd2iz6yDk) for optimisation (mainly for PvP), that includes the use of Blink.

Basically, Blink is most effectively used as a distraction/evasion manoeuvre, rather than a means of getting to higher places. For example, in a PvP situation, it could be used to escape an enemy's line of fire, or to get closer to them to use a shotgun more effectively. The teleportation is a very effective way to break the line of sight an opponent might have on you, whereas using Glide allows them to keep a bead on you and continue to fill you with holes.

However, in *most* (but maybe not all) PvE situations, Glide would probably be a more optimal choice rather than Blink.